# How to create a horizontal node branch using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I create something like this in bootstrap ?

[image]

I was thinking of making 4 columns each one of the nodes using the grid layout. But the center node is taking more space than it should take.

Here is the bootply http://www.bootply.com/5ni6EJeTWM

As of now it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Should it be with bootstrap grid only?

Comment: @hunzaboy No, the application just needs to use bootstrap so that it remains responsive in smaller screens. So I want to leverage the functionalities provided by boostrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. It is not perfect but it should help you get on the track.

**UPDATED the code - FULLY RESPONSIVE NOW !!!**

```css
.node-list {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.node-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.node-list li p {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.node-list li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}

.node-list li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: -1
}

.node-list li:first-child:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="node-list">
  <li class="active">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this solution, however I cannot use this one as it is using a hard-coded value for creating lines.  Is it possible to make it wide enough to take the parent container's width ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. You need to tweak the code little bit :)

Comment: @FlyingGambit : Updated the code and made it responsive. Also on codepen: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/YpQWzj